# How to parse an xml that has non-xml data in it

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I am working with some xml in C# and am having some issues parsing an xml file due to the format it is in.  It has non xml data in the file and I have no control over the format of this file.  The file is "test.xml"(see below).  I am only concerned with the xml portion of the data, but am unsure the best way to go about accessing it.  Any thoughts or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

```
Test data -1
Smith, 2234

@@*j

Random--

@<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ConfigMessage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.Test.com/schemas/Test.test.Config">
  <Config>
    <Version>10</Version>
    <Build>00520</Build>
    <EnableV>false</EnableV>
    <BuildL>22</BuildL>
    <BuildP>\\testpath\test</BuildP>
  </Config>
</ConfigMessage>
@
```

Comment: you have to do it manually.  Find where the xml begins and ends and trim your string down to that.

Comment: I wouldn't describe this as "an XML with non-XML data in it". I would described it as a non-XML file with XML data in it. The only clue you've given as to the format of the non-XML container is a single example, which isn't enough to draw any general rules, but you basically need to extricate the XML part and then send it to an XML parser.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Michael.  I agree with your conclusion...Regarding the file type, it is technically an xml file(.xml) and it does have non-xml data in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the whole file into a string that contains anything within the first '<' and the last '>' characters detected on the file. Then you can treat it as normal XML from there. If there's random non-XML elements throughout it though you will need to add additional logic to detect starting/stopping XML "blocks".

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you such solution: open your pseudo-xml like simple text-file, read whole text, after that, with using regex you ought to take xml document (part of primordial document that is able to be converted to XML [|startTag|*any symbols*|/endTag|]), put it into XDocument (in memory) and now parse it like XML-file.